# Old school Image map with a 2 overlay states

Tags: jquery, html

I have been asked to create an image map something I havent needed to do in I dont know how long :)

The base image is a circle with areas left out for the overlays [image: Circle Image]

There are 2 states of the icon images (on/off) Below is an example .All 3 images are the same size the icon related images are the same just a different shade over colour for a hover affect.

[image]

How is my best way to achieve this?
I have created this so far

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
<area shape="rect" coords="242,47,376,104" href="#" id="availiblity-manager" class="a-am"/>
<area shape="rect" coords="259,124,385,176" href="#"  id="capicaty-manager" class="a-capm"/>
<area shape="rect" coords="201,204,324,260" href="#" id="configuration-manager" class="a-confm" />
```

Some basic query to apply an on state to area class like

```
$('.a-am').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('on');
}, function () {
   $(this).removeClass('on');
});
```

I think its the .css where I am a little stuck as I am not sure how to align each of the area shapes

```
#Map .a-am
{
display:block;
background:url("../Content/Images/map2.png");
background-position:-256px -58px;
height:33px;
width:109px;
}

#Map .a-am.on
{
display:block;
background:url("../Content/Images/map3.png");
background-position:-256px -58px;
height:33px;
width:109px;
}
```

Can someone suggest how I should be aligning the icon images over the circle?

Comment: Does it actually have to be an image map? You could absolutely position those icons (as normal anchor links) over the circle background and achieve the same effect, and the result would be semantically better, IMO.

Comment: Hi ctcherry, Yeah doesnt have to be an image map at all. Would I need to slice up the 2 overlay images and then just add them as anchors? not 100% sure on the positioning of them tho

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to use an image map.  As ctcherry states in his comment, it'd be best to just place the items on the page.

Further, using CSS sprites, you don't need to do any slicing.  Just use that first image you posted for your background of the UL, and then take all the icons and smush them together to create an icon sprite set.  The background of your anchors should all point to this icon set and then you adjust the background position.

I'd do something like this:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="house"><a href="#">nice description</a></li>
    <li class="chart"><a href="#">nice description</a></li>
    <li class="etc"><a href="#">nice description</a></li>
    <li class="etc"><a href="#">nice description</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
background: url(somefilepathtobackground.png) no-repeat;
width: something;
height: something;
}

ul li a {
display: block;
text-indent: -9999px;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
background-image: url(somefilepathtoiconset.png) no-repeat;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
}

ul li.house {
position: absolute;
top: something;
left: something;
background-position: something;
}
```

I hope this is clear.  If not, let me know!

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites